# Calling delete on array of Matlab class objects

Tags: matlab, oop

If MyObj is a classdef, and I have an array of them

```
objs = [MyObj(), MyObj()];
```

then if I call

```
delete(objs);
```

the delete method for MyObj is called, as I would expect. 
If MyObj subclasses from handle, the delete method is called for each object in the array. However, if it is NOT subclassed from handle, then it appears that the entire array is passed to the delete method. However, I can't find this behavior in the docs, while I can find the handle behavior in the docs.

Is this really the correct interpretation of what I'm seeing? What is the normal practice to deal with this? Just subclass from handle, or check for an array in the delete method and delete each element in turn? Is there a downside to inheriting from handle (aside from having reference semantics, that is)? For the non-handle case, are there are cases that have to be accounted for?

Answer (score 3):

Handle classes have a *destructor* method called `delete`. The method is implicitly implemented by MATLAB, but you can overload it yourself to implement custom destructor behaviour.

The destructor method is called implicitly by MATLAB when the object needs to be destroyed (is no longer referenced anywhere), or can be explicitly called by you. It's called separately for each element in an array (as you've noticed).

Value classes do not have a destructor method. They may have a method called `delete`, but it's just like any other method (in particular, it's not called implicitly when the object is destroyed, and it's not called separately for each object in an array).

To emphasize that last bit, create `objs` as you did in your question, with an array of value classes. But then instead of explicitly calling `delete(objs)`, just say `objs = []`. You'll notice that although the objects have been destroyed, your `delete` method has not been called at all (because despite being called `delete`, it wasn't a destructor because it was from a value class).

I'm not sure how to answer your question "what is the normal practice to deal with this". If you need a destructor, you need to use a handle class. I can't really imagine a situation where you'd want to use a destructor with a value class.

You can read more in the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html).